# how to check using which user shell is being executed

Tags: shell, autosys

I have a `korn` shell script which is being called from an `Autosys` job scheduler. However i wanted to know using which user name (from the scheduler) my script is being executed so that i can call related environment files inside my script.

Example:

`autosys job user = test`

`environment = QA`

In this scenario how can i capture user `test` inside my shell? i.e. who is calling the shell.

I tried using `ps -ef` however it is listing all the details and i am not good at autosys commands

Comment: Not sure about your complete requirement but you could use `whoami` inside your code before running the job. Also from outside(console) once job is kicked off you could use `ps -ef | grep your_job(or look for some keyword which your job will have)`, lemme know how it goes?

Comment: Look for the "owner" attribute in the Autosys Job JIL, the script would be executed from the same owner.

Comment: @teepu : You did not write what OS you are running, but if it is Linux, the environment variable `USER` is set on login to the user name. But since some rogue process might have modified it, I would not rely safety critial programs on the correct setting of this variable.

Comment: `whoami` is returning the scheduler user name. Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about your complete requirement but you could use `whoami` inside your code before running the job. Also from outside(console) once job is kicked off you could use `ps -ef | grep your_job(or look for some keyword which your job will have.)`

Converted my commented(answer) to an answer here.